# Referring to ones own questions as examples, is it an accepted practice?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette, new-users

Is the following unethical?

I want to refer new users on the website to questions that I have asked. I want to help them to ask better questions by providing my questions as examples.

I am asking this because I believe it would help them to see the questions of a user who has a positive question-record.

Put differently  I was wondering if it was ok that when a new user asks a question that is of low quality that I refer them to my questions as a reference of how questions are asked since I have a positive question record?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Do you want to know if it is allowed to give your questions as examples to other users to help them understand how to ask questions?

Comment: @quid Yes, sorry I am answering questions but yes.

Comment: @quid you can see my question record?

Comment: Why don't you just point a specific questions and answers that you think are good models, without specifically referencing any user names?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I am referencing me personally I don't care my questions are meant to help people I joined the stack in 12th grade when I had to learn calculus on my own so by any means I would be fine having people look at my questions. I am always learning from the site and its users. I also ask questions constantly.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky: Okay, it's clear I don't understand what your question is. Neither did quid. Maybe describe the situation more explicitly?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I was wondering if it was ok that when a new user asks a question that is of low quality that I refer them to my questions as a reference of how questions are asked since I have a positive question record?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I edited the post a bit and included you last comment which is very clear.

Comment: While I think pointing to exemplar questions might be helpful, I'm not terribly comfortable with any user pointing only to their own questions to do so.  There is a great pool of good questions to which to refer a new user, so restricting that pool to your own questions seems a bit suspect to me.  You can help new users equally well, in an unbiased manner, by referring them to others' good questions.

Comment: @amWhy Why suspect? They are new users.

Comment: Because I hope you don't believe that the your questions are all the best examples of good questions on this site.  Why draw attention strictly to one's own questions and/or answers, when there are other great questions and answers?  Do you really think only your questions offer the best exemplars of good questions on this site?

Comment: The idea to guide users to exemplar questions is a good one.  The idea that your pool of exemplar questions come from strictly your questions is not such a good idea.

Comment: If it were me, I'd be far from willing to trawl through thousands of questions desperately trying to find a "good" one, when I have at my fingertips a number of questions which are apparently good enough to rate a considerable number of upvotes. If I'm responding to the question by providing an example, I'm going to use exactly whichever example I feel like, and if it's one of mine, that's what it's going to be. I don't see why it's anyone else's business to say nay.

Comment: @amWhy That's the question is if it's ok that to reference a user who is struggling with asking a question why isn't there a gallery of questions for users to see a specific question reference guide.

Comment: I agree; see my comment below yours, below the answer.  I think pointing users to good exemplars of questions is a *great idea*.  But since questions cover so many fields of math, finding good questions in the related field of the asker is likely more helpful than trying to find a question in one's own pool of questions which may not be so translatable.

Comment: Except, @PrimeMover, many may see such a choice as self-interested.  I would likely go out of my way to point such an OP to an even better question than the one you personally asked and are attached to.  Please read the answer to this question.  I believe it is as sound as an answer can be.

Comment: Self-interest is what drives motivation throughout the entire world. I hope you're not trying to suggest that it's a bad thing. But whether or not, if I have some good questions at my fingertips, those are the ones I will use. Life's too short to go hunting for other stuff, just because it's unfashionable to recognise one's own motivations for what they are.

Comment: @PrimeMover  Not everyone throughout the entire world adheres to your world-view, and it's awfully arrogant for you to think we all do.  It just shows you may not be the best judge of whether the question *you* asked and use to refer a user to is a good one, to the rest of the world.  I doubt you are any more objective that the rest of us.  We're all biased in favor of our own work and views.  But you can do what you want, just as others can intervene in problematic behavior if they see it.

Comment: "Please read the answer to this question. I believe it is as sound as an answer can be". And yet, as the writer of that answer I probably shouldn't point to it as an example of a good answer. Current mood: [Bertrand Russel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

Comment: A healthy amount of humility is needed to temper self-interest.  (me)  I think you clearly exhibit such temperance, @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: Just because not everyone has the same worldview as me does not mean my worldview is any less valid. As for objectively judging my questions, I pick the ones which have been categorised as "nice questions", don't I? If, say, 12 people have voted up one of my questions, then surely it's of adequate worth. But my point is that, yes, we are all biased in favour of our own work, I'm just honest about it.

Comment: @amWhy: I thank you, but really, I'll do anything to make a math-based Dad joke.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly permitted. Speaking for myself, though, I find I am not the best judge of my own writing. One reason for this is that I often have a very clear mental picture of a situation, and it only takes a few words to re-awaken that image in my mind. But sometimes I find out that the same writing does a not-as-good job at creating that image in the minds of other people.

However, if someone else's writing was effective at communicating their ideas to me I can be more confident that it would serve as a good model.

So I would say, yes, if you think you've got a nice question or answer go ahead and share it as an example, but I think other people's answers that have impressed you could make even better examples.

Comment: I was thinking if a gallery of the various user's questions could be used to help out in getting better quality posts in the initial user setup.

Comment: I think the potential pool of great questions to refer to offers far more varied examples than from only the pool of questions that you asked that you think are well-asked, @EnlightendFunky.  The idea of a thread, perhaps in meta, of good questions, could be helpful for new users, but I would want such a thread to not be dedicated to one user's questions.  Perhaps we could create a meta post to solicit suggestions for good examples of questions, allow users to vote on them, and pare down the suggestions to create a final meta post/gallery of good questions.

Comment: @amWhy thank you I am not trying to make it seem like any questions from any user if they have a good positive question record like take the top questions of each tag that great questions, good questions, and mediocre questions. That to me seems like a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I think having such a meta thread of questions the community considers well-written, and to which we can refer new users is a great idea!